# Boost/Step-Up Switching Regulator Issue: Only Functional with 5V or Higher Input Voltage (MYRBP500080W21RD Fixed 5v Step Up)

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm currently grappling with an unusual issue related to a fixed 5V boost/step-up switching regulator, specifically the MYRBP500080W21RD model (fixed 5v). As someone relatively new to electronics, I chose this particular DC/DC regulator due to its integrated inductor, aiming to simplify my setup for powering 16 dot star LEDs, each with a maximum draw of 20mA.

The problem I'm encountering revolves around the regulator's behaviour  with input voltages. It only appears to work as intended when the supplied voltage is 5 volts or more. Intriguingly, even when I set the power supply slightly above 5 volts (around 5.2V - 5.3V), I observe an increase in voltage being passed to the output pins.

The crux of the issue is that whenever the input voltage falls below 5.00V, there seems to be an instantaneous disconnect within the regulator. Consequently, power ceases to flow through it. As soon as the input voltage climbs back above 5V, the regulator springs back to life and allows power to flow once again.

I made an inadvertent mistake in my PCB design, placing the input capacitor after the inductor. I'm aware this contradicts the typical schematics for switching regulators, but I'm uncertain whether this error could be contributing to the problem.

In my quest to resolve this, I've undertaken various measures including:

- Double-checking all connections on the regulator for any potential
  loose or poorly soldered pins.
- Implementing a load resistor on the output capacitors to mimic the
  typical load, as outlined in the datasheet.
- Confirming that the enable pin of the regulator receives a proper
  high signal (3.3V).
- Experimenting with toggling the enable pin between high and low
  states at intervals. This action appears to toggle the regulator on and off when the input voltage is 5V or higher, but it doesn't impact the behaviour when the input voltage drops below 5V. It seems to create a complete disconnect between the input and output pins of the
  regulator.

I've reconstructed the board 2 times using entirely new components and PCBs, yet the issue persists consistently. I'm at a crossroads and wondering if it might be wise to consider ordering new PCBs with a different DC/DC regulator altogether. Any insights, advice, or guidance in the right direction would be incredibly appreciated. I'm eager to find a solution and learn from this experience. Thank you.

Data Sheet for the DC/DC regulator
https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8809985572894/MYRBP-B-W.pdf?1604930424000

[image]

Schematic diagram of the boost converter:

[image]

Comment: Plese add a schemtic diagram to the question

Comment: @RussellH I have edited the question to include a link to the schematic diagram of the boost converter  (at the very bottom)

Comment: Please add a link to the data sheet of the device.

Comment: For future reference, please draw all negative and ground reference lines pointing down. Don’t cross over symbols.

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, just letting you know that I've included a link to the datasheet for the DC/DC converter.

Comment: @winny Absolutely, I'll make sure to incorporate your advice in my upcoming designs. Your suggestion to have all negative and ground reference lines pointing downward, while avoiding any overlap with symbols, makes a lot of sense. This approach should contribute to clearer and more organized schematics, enhancing overall readability and understanding. Thanks for sharing this helpful tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost converters cannot lower voltage, only increase it, so applying >5V to a 5V output device should just pass through the higher voltage without switching like you observe.

I think your issue is the placement of the output capacitor, which is part of the hot switching loop.  Here is the current being switched in your diagram:

[image]

As you can see your switching loop is so enormous it extends off the screen into unknown parts of your circuit.  I suspect the regulator cannot function with such an enormous inductance on the switching node and so turns off, which is why you're only able to see 5V pass through.

What you could try is bodging in an additional 22uF MLCC capacitor like this (using the absolute shortest wires possible):

[image]

Which would shorten the loop to something reasonable.  See if that gets the converter to start switching.

Comment: Hi,

I just wanted to drop you a quick note to say thank you for your fantastic help. Your explanation about the switching loop and the input/output capacitor placement was right on the money. I followed your advice, added the 22uF MLCC capacitor, and guess what? The regulator is now switching perfectly.

Your expertise and willingness to assist have been a game-changer for me. Thanks a million for your valuable guidance!

Best regards,
Kyle

Comment: @kk3050  Great!  One other piece of advice if you order new boards:  the input capacitor position makes sense (ok to pass through the inductor pad) but put it closer to the chip.  You can move that via to the other side of the cap and put the cap as close as you can to the regulator.  Basically, all caps as close as possible between + and GND.  Big loops form big inductors which isolate the capacitor from the load.  You might also put the GND via on the GND pad of the regulator if thermal dissipation is a concern to carry more heat away.